# Cheerio multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to retrieve links from one page and then make additional requests to fetch the wanted pages. Printing out the response body directly works, but the new instance of cheerio does not work. It just prints a blank line. See code below

```
const request = require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const baseUrl = '...'

request(`${baseUrl}/...`, (error, response, articles) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    const $ = cheerio.load(articles)

    $('.feedArticleList')
      .children('li')
      .each((i, el) => {
        const link = $(el).children('a').attr('href')
        request(baseUrl + link, (error, response, article) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
          } else {
            console.log(article) // this works
            const $2 = cheerio.load(article)
            console.log($2('.Text').text()) // this just prints a blank line
          }
        })
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: what does `$2` print?

Comment: @Mekicha it print out the object (looks the same as `$`)

Comment: Are you sure you have the `.Text` class in the article then? Just wondering. If yes, try: `.html()` and see what it prints.

Comment: The baseUrl wasn't properly configured for the second request call, all good now... thanks anyway hehe